# wso2 IS 5.0 sp1 : Username case sensitive for some user

Tags: authentication, wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

Obrserving a strange behaviour with WSO2 IS 5.0 SP1 with AD configured as primary store : For some users username in CAPS works fine whereas in small case it fails authentication.
The carbon logs just says that it has failed authentication. Not sure why does it allows login for some users in both cases.

Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks in advance

Regards,
Cijoy

Comment: Seems related to https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-3311. Please have a look. Since IS 5.1.0 is out.Can you try this with latest?

Comment: Thanks Harsha, but I had added the following property in user-mgmt.xml to make it case insensitive <Property name="GetRoleListOfInternalUserSQL">SELECT UM_ROLE_NAME FROM UM_HYBRID_USER_ROLE, UM_HYBRID_ROLE WHERE UPPER(UM_USER_NAME)=UPPER ( ? ) AND UM_HYBRID_USER_ROLE.UM_ROLE_ID=UM_HYBRID_ROLE.UM_ID AND UM_HYBRID_USER_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_HYBRID_ROLE.UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_HYBRID_USER_ROLE.UM_DOMAIN_ID=(SELECT UM_DOMAIN_ID FROM UM_DOMAIN WHERE UM_TENANT_ID=? AND UM_DOMAIN_NAME=?)</Property>......It works for some but not all the users

Comment: It's better if you can enable debug logs in  org.wso2.carbon.user.core, you can see more debug logs about authentication failure. It will give more insight